# Number Format Code in excel getting Inavalid

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, format, cell-formatting

In one of my project in which it export data into excel, we were trying to set the custom number format code for cells.
But for one particular string the number format code was this

#######.##.##0#0#########################################################.##.###00######################################################.##.#0#00#####

while trying to open excel I was getting a repair message.
[image]

I tried setting the custom format with the above mentioned format code. But I was getting error message message that this format code can't be set.

The value for the corresponding format code is a long sentence I am getting this code from an old method in my project. Can anyone please guide me why this format code is invalid.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I can confirm that that format code is invalid in Excel. What are you trying to accomplish with this numberFormat Code? Perhaps an example of your raw data in and desired output with formatting would be helpful.

Comment: Iam grtting this format code form an API. that was written long back. any insight on why this is invalid. so that I can correct it . i can't share the data as it is confidential. if any idea on what makes its invalid will be so helpful for me.

Comment: *Why would you need to share any real data in order to provide sample data that demonstrates the problem?*  With valid symbols in your numberformat string, you will just have to experiment using Excel until you find a format that works for your purpose, and then use that in your c# code.